# Connecting multiple arrays in javascript not concat

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looping through JSON data to pull out dates and placing them into an array. The following code is an example of my code inside the loop.

```
// get the JSON data
var foo = "2013-03-28";

// split foo into an array
var bar = foo.split('-');        // Output ["2013", "03", "08"] 

// putting array in necessary format
for (a in bar) {
    bar[a] = parseInt(arr[a]);   // Output [2013, 3, 8] 
}
```

Now that I have my array the way I need it, the next time it loops I want to add to a bigger array such as follows

```
// Trying to add each new array to a bigger array
baz += bar

// Sample output I'm looking for
baz = [ [2013, 3, 8], [2013, 2, 12], [2013, 1, 22], ... ]
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [You should not use for..in on Arrays!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#arrayNote) Where order is important anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add an element to the end of an array:

```
baz.push(bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **var foo = "2013"-"03"-"28"** is not a string .. To add an element in a array , use push method..

```
var foo = "2013-03-28";// This is a string 

// split foo into an array
var bar = foo.split('-');        // Output ["2013", "03", "08"] 

baz.push(bar);
```

It also does the same

Example :

```
var array = [];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    var a = [2012,i,25];
    array.push(a);
    alert(array);
}
```

[Running Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNjGw/)

Comment: @user2234467 You are mistaken. You are most likely using `alert` or `document.write` to look at the contents of the array. Since that will expand all the arrays to comma separated strings it will look like a single dimensional array when it is really multidimensional. You should always use `console.log` for debugging.

Comment: See my edited post .. The fiddle consists of a array with 5 elements in which each element is an array of 3 elements

Comment: @user2234467 [See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skAAy/) to help you understand as well

Comment: @user2234467 it's not combining the arrays .. Array usually shows the elements by comma separated .. Well if you use string , you will come to know about this